# How to link to specified page in PDF in its HTTPS form?

Tags: hyperref, pdf

I am trying to set up a hyperlink so that when the user clicks on the link to the PDF, it would go *directly* to the desired page as shown below:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\hypersetup{
    colorlinks=true,
    linkcolor=cyan,
    filecolor=magenta,      
    urlcolor=blue,
}
\begin{document}    
    Let's go to \href[page = 4]{https://personal.utdallas.edu/~herve/Abdi-EVD2007-pretty.pdf}{page 4} of this document.
\end{document}
```

However, it ends up going to the beginning of the page. Is there a way to properly set this up?

Comment: `\href{https://xxxx.pdf#page=4}` will work, but I need to check if it is possible to bind this to the page key.